# dplyr and mid-pipe messages

Tags: r, dplyr

I occasionally have long-running pipes, and I'd like a quick `message` as stages progress. I'm trying

```r
log_midpipe <- function(x, expr) { expr; x; }
```

(and have also tried `force(expr)`), but the message timing is all wrong.

```r
library(dplyr)
sleep <- function(x, time=3) { Sys.sleep(3); x; }
message(Sys.time(), " start"); 
mtcars %>%
  log_midpipe(message(Sys.time(), " hello1")) %>%
  sleep(.) %>%
  log_midpipe(message(Sys.time(), " hello2")) %>%
  sleep(.) %>%
  head(3)
message(Sys.time(), " done")
# 2021-04-16 08:51:09 start
# 2021-04-16 08:51:12 hello2
# 2021-04-16 08:51:15 hello1
# 2021-04-16 08:51:15 done
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

The out-of-order is (I believe) because of how the arguments are evaluated: lazily, and once converted from a pipe to a nested "parenthetic-like" stack of commands, the `"hello1"` messaging is the outer-most, which means it is evaluated *last*.

Is there an easy way to get mid-pipe logging, in real time?

I'm hoping to get

```r
# 2021-04-16 08:51:09 start
# 2021-04-16 08:51:09 hello1
# 2021-04-16 08:51:12 hello2
# 2021-04-16 08:51:15 done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get them into the right order by forcing `log_midpipe` to evaluate `x` first.

This should work for real examples where the long running code is part of the `x` in `sleep` and not a separate call beforehand since `Sys.sleep` doesn't need any parts of `x` evaluated.

```
log_midpipe <- function(x, expr) {
  result <- x
  expr 
  result
}
```

A `sleep` that needs `x` as an input to do its long running process would look like this and prints in the right intervals:

```
sleep <- function(x, time=3) { 
  result <- x
  Sys.sleep(3)
  result
}
```

Comment: I had focused so much on `force(x)` in `log_midpipe` that I hadn't thought to force the expression as well, nice. *And* ... you caught the issue with my contrived (not-used-in-production) `sleep` function, which suggests that the issue can also be exacerbated by the intermediate pipe steps, not just the mid-pipe log. Thanks!